# Incorrect behaviour of a for loop

Tags: delphi

I have encountered some incorrect behaviour in a procedure to write a UT8String to a stream (Delphi 10.3). The procedure is very straightforward and reads:

```
procedure StreamWriteUTF8String(Stream: TStream; Value: UTF8String);
  {Writes a UTF8 character string to a  Stream}
var
  n, i: longword;
begin
  n:= Length(Value);
  StreamWriteCardinal(Stream, n);
  for i:= 0 to n-1 do
    Stream.WriteBuffer(Value[i+1], SizeOf(UTF8Char));
end;
```

When an empty Value string is passed to the procedure, so that n, the string length, is zero, the bounds of the for loop control variable i should be 0 to -1. Therefore in this case the statement Stream.WriteBuffer inside the for loop should not be executed. This is because the termination test, i<= UpperBound, which should be executed before the loop body, should evaluate to False. It is my understanding that a for loop should be implemented in such a way that the body should be executed zero or more times depending on the bounds of the control variable tested before proceeding to the body.

However I am finding that in the case of n=0 the compiled code does not skip the statement Stream.WriteBuffer as one would expect, with the result that the Value[i+1] gives rise to an access violation exception.

Let me say that I have similar procedures for writing other types of string to a stream, most of which can handle a zero length string without any problem.

Can anyone suggest why in this case the loop does not appear to be working as it ought?

Comment: And this is why I tell everyone to compile their code with overflow and range checking emabled in debug config - it would have blown up at the n-1 for n=0 (also see https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16751)

Comment: On a side note, you don't need the loop at all, you can and should write the entire string in one call: `Stream.WriteBuffer(PUTF8Char(Value)^, n * SizeOf(UTF8Char));`

Answer (score 10):

You have declared `n` as a `LongWord`, which is an *unsigned* integer of 32 bits.

Therefore, `n - 1` will wrap around and be `4294967295`.

You should use the `Integer` type instead, for both `i` and `n`. That's a 32-bit *signed* integer, so `n - 1` will indeed be `-1`.

Comment: Also, because [`Length()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Length) returns an `Integer` to begin with, not a `LongWord`.